# Any good tutorials about 2d drawing and painting?

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, image-processing, drawing

I'm trying to code raster graphics editor, but I can't find any good tutorials about 2d drawing in the Internet.
All that I found is [Lode's Computer Graphics Tutorial](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/)

It shows how to implement pencil, brush, flood fill, etc. But that's not enough. I find myself trying to re-invent the wheel, you know. :)
I'm pretty sure there're a lot of algorithms, but I can't find them. Where can I find them? Language is not very important(but I'm writing on C++ with Qt), just need to know basics.

Comment: Why do you want to code up a raster graphics editor? In these days, where GIMP, Paint.NET, and others are all readily and *freely* available, why do you want to write up an editor?

Comment: I think it's nice practice to improve my coding skills

Answer (score 0):

### Use Qt's Documentation

Since you're using Qt, here is a good starting point: [Basic Drawing Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/painting-basicdrawing.html)

### Sources

- [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsscene.html)
- [QImage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html)
- [QPixmap](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpixmap.html)

Comment: Of course, I've read these articles, but they don't contain exactly what I want. For example I want to add selection tool, and I'll have to create it from the beginning, knowing, that there're more convinient methods, that I'll "re-invent". ;D

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you're looking for? Just graphics algorithms?

Comment: Yes. I've found a lot of books about image processing, but they're good only for adding different image effects or transforming. I posted link to good tutorials and chapters like in "2D Drawing" is exactly what I want to find